# react js state in parent component isn't re rendering in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i am trying to make a filter for my products. And for that i initialised a state in a component called Product that has all the filters. And then, based on the input of the checkboxes that are in a child component that is called Category, the filter state changes.

here is my code :

Product.jsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Filter from "./Filter.jsx";
import styles from "../styles/products.module.css";

const products = {
  prod1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "prod1",
    category: "laptops",
    price: "80",
    description: { brand: "lenovo", processor: "intel core i7" },
  },
  prod2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "prod2",
    category: "laptops",
    price: "10",
    description: { brand: "lenovo", processor: "intel core i7" },
  },
  prod3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "prod3",
    category: "laptops",
    price: "100",
    description: { brand: "msi", processor: "intel core i5" },
  },
  prod4: {
    id: 4,
    name: "prod4",
    category: "laptops",
    price: "200",
    description: { brand: "msi", processor: "intel core i3" },
  },
  prod5: {
    id: 5,
    name: "prod5",
    category: "phones",
    price: "50",
    description: { brand: "samsung", ram: "8gb", storage: "64gb" },
  },
  prod6: {
    id: 6,
    name: "prod6",
    category: "phones",
    price: "50",
    description: { brand: "infinix", ram: "4gb", storage: "128gb" },
  },
  prod7: {
    id: 7,
    name: "prod7",
    category: "phones",
    price: "50",
    description: { brand: "oppo", ram: "8gb", storage: "256gb" },
  },
  prod8: {
    id: 8,
    name: "prod8",
    category: "accessories",
    price: "99",
    description: { type: "keyboard" },
  },
  prod9: {
    id: 9,
    name: "prod9",
    category: "accessories",
    price: "75",
    description: { type: "mouse" },
  },
};

function Products() {
  const filter = {
    laptops: {
      brand: [],
      processor: [],
    },
    phones: {
      brand: [],
      ram: [],
      storage: [],
    },
    accessories: {
      type: [],
    },
  };
  const [filterList, setFilterList] = useState(filter);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("all");
  const [range, setRange] = useState(9999);

  const getFilterState = () => {
    return filterList;
  };
  const setFilterState = (list) => {
    setFilterList(list);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.productsContainer}>
      <Filter
        range={[range, setRange]}
        category={[category, setCategory]}
        getfilterList={getFilterState}
        setFilterState={setFilterState}
      />
      <table className={styles.productsListContainer}>
        <tr className={styles.tableColumn}>
          <th className={styles.tableRow}>id</th>
          <th className={styles.tableRow}>Name</th>
          <th className={styles.tableRow}>price</th>
        </tr>

        {Object.keys(products).map((key) => {
          let flag = true;
          const product = products[key];
          const categ = product.category;
          if (
            (categ === category || category === "all") &&
            product.price <= range
          ) {
            Object.entries(filter[categ]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
              if (
                !(
                  value.length === 0 || value.includes(product.description[key])
                )
              ) {
                flag = false;
              }
            });
            if (flag) {
              return (
                <tr className={styles.tableColumn} key={product.id}>
                  <td className={styles.tableRow}>{product.id}</td>
                  <td className={styles.tableRow}>{product.name}</td>
                  <td className={styles.tableRow}>{product.price}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
            return null;
          }
          return null;
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

Filter.jsx:

```
import CategoryComponent from "./Category";
import styles from "../styles/filter.module.css";

function Filter({
  filters,
  dispatch,
  category,
  getfilterList: filterList,
  setFilterState: setFilterList,
  range: rangeState,
}) {
  const [Category, setCategory] = category;
  const [Range, setRange] = rangeState;

  const handleCategoryChanged = (event, categ, key) => {
    let list = filterList();
    if (list[categ][key].includes(event.currentTarget.value)) {
      list[categ][key] = list[categ][key].filter(
        (val) => val !== event.currentTarget.value
      );
    } else {
      list[categ][key].push(event.currentTarget.value);
    }
    setFilterList(list);

    if (Category !== categ) {
      setCategory(categ);
    } else {
      let flag = false;
      Object.keys(filterList()[categ]).forEach((key) => {
        const obj = filterList()[categ][key];
        if (obj.length !== 0) flag = true;
      });
      if (!flag) {
        setCategory("all");
      }
    }
  };

  const handleRangeChanged = (event) => {
    setRange(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="filter-container">
      <h1>{Category}</h1>
      <CategoryComponent
        filterList={filterList()}
        setFilterList={setFilterList}
        category={Category}
        handleCategoryChanged={handleCategoryChanged}
        categories={{
          brand: ["lenovo", "msi", "asus"],
          processor: ["intel core i3", "intel core i5", "intel core i7"],
        }}
      >
        laptops
      </CategoryComponent>
      <CategoryComponent
        filterList={filterList()}
        setFilterList={setFilterList}
        handleCategoryChanged={handleCategoryChanged}
        category={Category}
        categories={{
          brand: ["samsung", "infinx", "oppo"],
          ram: ["8gb", "4gb", "2gb"],
          storage: ["64gb", "128gb", "256gb"],
        }}
      >
        phones
      </CategoryComponent>
      <CategoryComponent
        filterList={filterList()}
        setFilterList={setFilterList}
        category={Category}
        handleCategoryChanged={handleCategoryChanged}
        categories={{
          type: ["keyboard", "mouse", "screen"],
        }}
      >
        accessories
      </CategoryComponent>
      <div className={styles.priceRangeContainer}>
        <input
          type="range"
          min="0"
          max="9999"
          className={styles.priceRange}
          value={Range}
          onChange={handleRangeChanged}
        />
        <span>{Range}DT</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Filter;
```

Category.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/category.module.css";
import arrow from "../img/angle-up-solid-svgrepo-com.svg";

export default function Category({
  handleCategoryChanged,
  children,
  categories,
  category,
  filterList,
  setFilterList,
}) {
  const [hiddenClass, setHiddenClass] = useState(styles.hidden);
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (hiddenClass) setHiddenClass("");
    else setHiddenClass(styles.hidden);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h5>{category}</h5>
      <div onClick={handleClick} className={styles.categoryBox}>
        {children} <img style={{ width: 15 }} src={arrow} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.hiddenScroll + " " + hiddenClass}>
        {Object.entries(categories).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              <h5>{key}:</h5>
              <ul>
                {value.map((val) => {
                  console.log(filterList);
                  return (
                    <li key={val}>
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        name={val}
                        id={val}
                        value={val}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          handleCategoryChanged(e, children, key)
                        }
                      />
                      <label htmlFor={val}>{val}</label>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is when i run my program the state changes when i check an only one checkbox, but when i click on more checkboxes nothing changes.

EDIT:
my components hierarchy :

```
products.jsx
    filter.jsx
        Category.jsx
```

in products.jsx :
i have a state filterList that has all the filters i need.

```
const filter = {
    laptops: {
      brand: [],
      processor: [],
    },
    phones: {
      brand: [],
      ram: [],
      storage: [],
    },
    accessories: {
      type: [],
    },
  };
  const [filterList, setFilterList] = useState(filter);
```

in Filter.jsx:
i have state filterList that was passed as a prop from the Products component.
and a function that handles any checkbox change from it's child component.

```
const handleCategoryChanged = (event, categ, key) => {
    let list = filterList();
    //testing if the value is already in the filterList if true we remove it
    if (list[categ][key].includes(event.currentTarget.value)) {
      list[categ][key] = list[categ][key].filter(
        (val) => val !== event.currentTarget.value
      );
    } else {
      // else we add it to the list
      list[categ][key].push(event.currentTarget.value);
    }
    setFilterList(list);
```

Category.jsx:

here i created all my checkboxes with the onChange event.

But the problem is when more than one checkbox gets changed, my filterList state does not get re rendered.

Comment: You've got a lot going on here.  Can you make a fiddle of it too?  One code smell I see is `filterList={filterList()}`.  You don't usually pass a function call to a child.  Usually you pass a ref to the function so the child can call it.

Comment: i already tried passing the ref. It's the same thing because what i did was just calling the function to get an object that this function returns and then passing it to props. Sorry if my post isn't so clear. I'll try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `useState` in your `Filter.jsx`

Replacing

```
const [Category, setCategory] = category;
const [Range, setRange] = rangeState;
```

With

```
const [Category, setCategory] = useState(category);
const [Range, setRange] = useState(rangeState);
```

A small working example could be found at [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-framework-t1x17f?file=/src/Filter.jsx:329-339)

⚠️ You did not provide the parent of `Filter.jsx` so in the example only the laptop brands are working

Comment: I was just trying to get the props that are already states. I don't think i need the useState because when i used the useState,it didn't work for me.